# Maximum(:created_at) does not give the timestamp in local time format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, timezone, timestamp, max

`Maximum(:created_at)` does not give the timestamp in local time format but in UTC.

I am using Rails 2.3.8

Is there another way to get the latest created_at in local time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `getlocal` method of the `Time` class, to obtain the local time from an UTC time.

Comment: Page.maximum(:created_at).getlocal # usage example to avoid confusion with class method and instance method